# SF book with humans landing on an alien planet where the Brutons are one of the main races

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I read this back in the 70's or possibly the early 80's.

The book took place on an alien planet, the Brutons being an aggressive race; I just cannot remember that much about the plot. I believe the main characters were human and landed on the planet. The Brutons, from memory, were in conflict with another native species whom the humans befriended.

I think the author was quite new as I remember that the way he relayed the speech between the characters was very repetitive; for example, I think he used the phrase "he demanded" frequently when writing dialogue between characters.

This is my only online query, by the way.

Comment: Not sure if there is any connection, but the Donald Duck story "Zio Paperone e l'invasione dei maxi-robot" (https://inducks.org/story.php?c=I+TL+1301-BP) contains, at least in its German translation, an alien species called "Bruthon" from the planet "Bruthos". These aliens are antagonistic, though. Close to the end of the story there was (again, in the German translation) a pair of speech bubbles with repetitive speech, quite uncharacteristic of other Donald Duck comics.

Comment: @AlexanderKlauer You did better than I.  I couldn't find anything relevant with "bru{t|th}{o|a|e|i|ia|ai|ea|ie|io}n[s]"

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this book? Were there other races? Were the Brutons aliens or human? Was this set on Earth or another planet? What makes this scifi? Was there a hero? Was there a villain?